# Sql Query Builder Converting Data to char

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I've had this problem while trying to read a variable which gets a date, for example "14.07.2018" and compares it to a date column. How can I solve this? I want to show a schedule from a festival in a specific day(Orar.Data is the column which indicates the date).

[image]

Comment: The error seems to be saying your dates are being stored as text.  While this won't let you use them as actual dates, your particular format of day-month-year also won't even let them _sort_ correctly as text.  You need to fix your storage problem.

Comment: I've put the column Data Type as date and saved it as 14.07.2018, so you're saying that I should change the date format?

Comment: Oh...I didn't know it was already date type.  I don't know your database well, disregard my earlier comment then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to always have both sides of the comparison as equals, i.e. comparing oranges to oranges, so to speak. 
To that end, it is a good practice to modify both sides, LHS and RHS, to the same format.

SQL provides the "convert" function that does this. More documentation [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/).

Your query should be:

```js
SELECT 
 * --insert your columns
FROM 
 Scena 
INNER JOIN
 Orar ON Scena.Id_scena = Orar.Id_scena 
INNER JOIN
 Artist ON Orar.Id_artist = Artist.Id_artist
WHERE 
 Scena.Titlu_scena = @var
AND
 convert(varchar, Orar.Data, 9) = convert(varchar, @var1, 9)
```

Comment: Great to hear! Cheers!